# VBA function to validate whether cell contents is date, returning true/false

Tags: excel, vba, validation, types

I'm pulling data from a report into excel, and want to strip the rows that contain headers/spaces/other guff. I can't show you the data, so you'll have to take my word for it that checking for a valid date in a set column is the best way of determining whether to delete the row.

My issue is that the DateValue() seems to return true when the chosen cell contains a valid date format, but when I use it to validate a cell that does not contain a date it throws a type error (I would like 'false').

Is there a better function to use, or if not what is the best way to fiddle it?

```
Public TotalRowCount As Integer

Sub RemoveUnwantedRows()

    Call FindTotalRowCount

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While (i <= TotalRowCount)
        If DateValue(Cells(i, 13).Value) Then
            Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            TotalRowCount = TotalRowCount - 1
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to use `On Error Return False`, but if that is the best/neatest solution could someone please explain the scope of On Error?

Comment: `On Error Return False` is something unheard of.

Comment: [`DateValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function) generates a date. [`IsDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) checks if it's a date and returns true if the value is a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) or a string that can be parsed to a `Date`.

Comment: Somehow I managed to miss the IsDate function. I believe I also misremembered `On Error Resume` - it was the last thing I looked at briefly before the journey home.

Comment: RE your other point: I misremembered `On Error Resume` - it was the last thing I looked at briefly before the journey home.

I also managed to forget the `Not` in my if-statement above. I think it disappeared in testing.

Anyway, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all rows that do **not** contain a date in column 13:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim i As Long, TotalRowCount As Long
    TotalRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = TotalRowCount To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsDate(Cells(i, 13)) Then Cells(i, 13).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So you're going backwards to avoid a) the diminishing total row count, and b) the fact that the row number gets deleted? That is pretty nifty.

Could you explain why/if EntireRow.Delete is better than Rows().Delete?

Comment: @BlankedyBlank using `Rows()` might actually be better.